# collapse row by row with (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, animation

I want to hide/show a lot of contents by id

Here is an example:

```
<a href="#" class="click"> title here </a>
<p class="content" id="1">
    text here ...
</p>

<a href="#" class="click" id="2"> another title here </a>
<p class="content">
    another text here ...
</p>
```

I can add an ID into my HTML code. 
How Can I get it by jQuery?

The jQuery lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.content').hide();
        $('.click').click(function() {
           $('.content').slideToggle(500);
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to show/hide the content relating to the link clicked? You're not looking for IDs, you're looking for some better Javascript :)

Try something like this:

```
$('.click').click(function()
{
    $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
}
```

Comment: the code don't work. I added a `$('.list').hide();` but still don't work

Comment: then I'm afraid I don't know what you're trying to do, I'm sorry :/

Comment: You need to wrap that function with a `$(function () { [Place above function here] });`
so that it will be registered when the DOM has completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, instead of targeting a class, target an id:

```
$('#content').hide();
```

.. and change your HTML accordingly:

```
<p id="content">
```

Comment: NO I mean I have a lo of content :)

Comment: Inside the code this line means you're wrong: <p class="content">. One should use $(".content") selector

Answer (score 0):

If the p.content is always immediately after the .click link you can do this:

```
$('.click').click(function(ev){ 
   $(this).next().toggle(); 
   ev.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate each selection, i think:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MooExample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#click").click(function() {
                    $("li").each(function() {
                        $(this).toggle();
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>moo</li>
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>fasoo</li>
            <li>moasf</li>
            <li>moosadg</li>
            <li>moo1</li>
            <li>moo412</li>
            <li>moo613a</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="button" id="click" onclick="moo()" value="click" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPD**: if you wanna hide some range of elements, you could alter selector (to select needed range items only) or use each(index) form either:

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    $("li").each(function(index) {
        if (index > 2 && index < 6)
            $(this).slideToggle(500);
        });
});
```

Comment: Not that what I have. I just want to collapse some contents

Comment: well, alter the each funtion then: $("li").each(function() { $(this).slideToggle(500); });

i've updated my answer. take a look over it for details.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code

***HTML***

```
<a href="#" class="click"> title here </a>
<p class="content" id="content1">
     text here ...
</p>
<br />
<a href="#" class="click" id="content2"> another title here </a>
<p class="content">
    another text here ...
</p>
```

***CSS***

```
p.content
{
    display: none;
}
```

***jQuery***

```
$(function(){
    var openedElem = null;
    $("a.click").click(function(){
        var nextElem = $(this).next();

        if (openedElem !== null) {
            if (openedElem.attr("id") === nextElem.attr("id")) {
                return false;
            }
            openedElem.slideUp();
        }

        openedElem = nextElem.slideDown();
        return false; // to prevent the default action
    });
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ppsxw/)

Comment: I get the id in `<p class="content" id="content1">` from my mysql table. SO the id in increment. There is a solution? Thanks

Comment: No, it won't cause a problem.